# How to solve SceneKit double not supported error?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have been looking into SceneKit for iOS over the past couple of days. I came across an issue when trying to create custom geometry. Whenever I tried to display the geometry, it would not draw, and show me this error during runtime.

SceneKit: error, C3DRendererContextSetupResidentMeshSourceAtLocation - double not supported

I created a playground targeting iOS to test a more simple example of custom geometry, and looked into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493273/custom-scenekit-geometry-in-swift-on-ios-not-working-but-equivalent-objective-c) about custom geometry using swift vs objective c.

I tried another project using objective c and still received the same error message.

The error does not appear when targeting the desktop on either the playground or a full project, and the geometry draws correctly. Only when targeting iOS does the error message occur.

```
import SceneKit
import QuartzCore   // for the basic animation
import XCPlayground // for the live preview

// create a scene view with an empty scene
var sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
var scene = SCNScene()
sceneView.scene = scene

// start a live preview of that view
XCPShowView("The Scene View", sceneView)

// default lighting
sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true

// a camera
var camera = SCNCamera()
var cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = camera
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 10)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

// create geometry
var verts = [SCNVector3(x: 0,y: 0,z: 0),SCNVector3(x: 1,y: 0,z: 0),SCNVector3(x: 0,y: 1,z: 0)]

let src = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: &verts, count: 3)
let indexes: [CInt] = [0, 1, 2]

let dat  = NSData(
  bytes: indexes,
  length: sizeof(CInt) * countElements(indexes)
)
let ele = SCNGeometryElement(
  data: dat,
  primitiveType: .Triangles,
  primitiveCount: 1,
  bytesPerIndex: sizeof(CInt)
)
let geo = SCNGeometry(sources: [src], elements: [ele])

let nd = SCNNode(geometry: geo)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(nd)
```

Here is the code I am using in the playground to draw a triangle. The same code is used when targeting the desktop.

How can I fix this and display the geometry for iOS?

Comment: you should share the code that builds the geometry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be an issue with `SCNVector3` being defined in terms of `CGFloat` for desktop (which can be either 32 or 64 bit depending on the host) and `Float` for iOS devices -- the iOS Simulator platform (which is what you get when targeting iOS in a playground) is neither quite like a device nor quite like OS X. [Filing a bug with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) would be a good idea.

In the meantime, a good workaround might be to use the more detailed initializer (that starts with `init(data:semantic:...`) to create your geometry source.

Answer (score 6):

I solved the error by changing how I was creating the geometry source.

By following [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150737/how-to-use-ios-swift-scenekit-scnscenerenderer-unprojectpoint-properly) method of creating the geometry sources the error was fixed and the triangle drew properly.

I believe the solution was in using

```
+ (instancetype)geometrySourceWithData:(NSData *)data
                              semantic:(NSString *)semantic
                           vectorCount:(NSInteger)vectorCount
                       floatComponents:(BOOL)floatComponents
                   componentsPerVector:(NSInteger)componentsPerVector
                     bytesPerComponent:(NSInteger)bytesPerComponent
                            dataOffset:(NSInteger)offset
                            dataStride:(NSInteger)stride
```

instead of

```
+ (instancetype)geometrySourceWithVertices:(const SCNVector3 *)vertices
                                     count:(NSInteger)count
```

because it specifies that I am using float components instead of double.

Comment: Thanks - this solved the problem for me. (The simpler call was working fine on all the devices I tried except for the iPhone 6+, which seemed to replace some vertices with world origin.)

Comment: a bit late, but have you tried adding a large number of nodes to a scene? Over 200? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941570/loading-a-lot-of-custom-nodes-to-scene-crashes-app

Comment: could you post the entire code for creating the geometry?

Answer (score 0):

More precisely, what got it to work for me was:

```
struct FloatPoint {
  var x: Float
  var y: Float
}
let textCoords = [FloatPoint]()
... fill it

let textureData = NSData(bytes: textCoords, length: textCoords.count * sizeof(FloatPoint.self))
let textSource = SCNGeometrySource(
  data: textureData as Data,
  semantic: SCNGeometrySourceSemanticTexcoord,
  vectorCount: textCoords.count,
  floatComponents: true,
  componentsPerVector: 2,
  bytesPerComponent: sizeof(Float.self),
  dataOffset: 0,
  dataStride: sizeof(FloatPoint.self)
)
```

I also filled a but with Apple