# Large C array not imported in Swift 5.2

Tags: c, swift

I am trying to import a C array that is 64kb meant to be a circular buffer for a log on a device. When I attempt to access this array in Swift I am met with the error

> Value of type 'logging' has no member 'data'

To attempt to answer potential questions about bridging, I am using other types from my imported C library that are defined in the same file that this mock code originates.

The code is setup as follows:

`logging.h`:

```
typedef struct _logging {
    uint8_t data[64*1024];
} logging;
```

In `ReadLog.swift`:

```
struct ReadLog {
    var log: logging = logging()

    func read() {
        //...Do some stuff...
        let char = log.data.0 // <- Error here 'Value of type 'logging' has no member 'data'
    }
}
```

Changing the size of data to 256 imported this member with no issue. (I don't know what the cutoff is).

What would be the best way to handle this?

Comment: I think your `log` variable should be a pointer, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050942/swift-use-c-struct

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try.

Comment: What is inside the header file? Swift doesn't see what is not inside headers. I don't think it has to be a pointer.

Comment: @Sulthan I've update the example to be a header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that C arrays are imported to Swift as a tuple, and tuples have a maximal arity (see for example [What is the limit (if any) to the tuple cardinality in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24432646/1187415)). The current limit in Swift 5 seems to be 4096 tuple elements.

A possible workaround is to create a C helper function which returns a pointer to the C array. With the [SE-0044 Import as member](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0044-import-as-member.md) feature this can made to look like a Swift property.

You only have to add the following code either in the C header file where the `logging` structure is defined, or in the bridging header file:

```
// Pointer to the data elements:
__attribute__((swift_name("getter:logging.dataPtr(self:)")))
static inline const uint8_t * _Nonnull loggingDataPtr(const logging * _Nonnull log)
{
    return log->data;
}
```

Now you can read the log data in the Swift code via the pointer:

```
struct ReadLog {
    var log = logging()

    func read() {
        //...Do some stuff...
        let char = log.dataPtr[0]
    }
}
```

But be aware that there is no array bounds checking, you must ensure that `log.dataPtr` is only used with indices within the array size.

If you want to read *and write* to the logging structure from Swift then change the helper function to

```
// Pointer to the data elements:
__attribute__((swift_name("getter:logging.dataPtr(self:)")))
static inline uint8_t * _Nonnull loggingDataPtr(logging * _Nonnull log)
{
    return log->data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this bit of information, it helped immensely!